# MIgrating to new web server, but IIS Website is not working in new Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I have migrated to new server and hosted my website, but it is not Loading.
When I tried to open Authentication roles, it shows error msg as shown below.
I used folder based publish Profile for generating the web.config files.

I verified below software's were installed.

1. .NET core Runtime and ASP.net core Runtime installed for .NET 8.0
2. Verified IIS roles are installed in Server manager.

Below is my Web.config file  (removed application information)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\configuration.MVC.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

[image: Installed IIS Roles and Error Msg]
[image: Error While Loading Website]

We are migrating our webserver and in my new webserver, website is not loading. I verified installed software's and IIS Roles, and everything is fine.
Kindly let me know if any issue in my Web.config or IIS roles.

Comment: We reinstalled .NET CORE hosting bundle and issue got resolved. Today I came across this article explaining about this issue.     https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-7.0